# Replacing Magento Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.7, hhvm

I'm in the process of migrating my company's development server from NGINX+PHP-FPM to NGINX+HHVM setup. Everything works perfectly out of the box, except a small thing in our Magento eCommerce 1.7 installation.

During testing, I have observed one error coming up frequently:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function stream_socket_enable_crypto() in 
/srv/www/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php on line 206
```

The offending line is:

```
if (!stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->_socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT)) {
```

After some [research](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1647) I found out that `stream_socket_enable_crypto()` is [not implemented yet](http://docs.hhvm.com//manual/en/function.stream-socket-enable-crypto.php). I tried to look for an alternative (either something that will let me rewrite the code while keeping it compatible with the rest of the system) or perhaps some Magento extension that alters how emails are sent. How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT** HHVM was installed from binary as described on [github project](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/HHVM-Pre-built-packages-for-Centos-6.4). Version info:

```
HipHop VM 3.1.0 (rel)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.1.0-0-g71ecbd8fb5e94b2a008387a2b5e9a8df5c6f5c7b
Repo schema: 88ae0db264d72ec2e2eb22ab25d717214aee568b
```

Comment: do you have any tutorial or benchmark ?

Comment: @WonderLand Tutorials on how to setup Magento with HHVM? There is plenty resources on [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=magento+hhvm). Good benchmark was published on [mgt-commerce](http://www.mgt-commerce.com/blog/magento-hhvm/). If you can find a way around `stream_socket_enable_crypto` not being implemented it may be worth doing - everything else seemed to work rather well (although we haven't done full testing). You may want to consider putting `varnish` in front of your webserver instead - doesn't decrease output generation but very much helps if you have large amount of users.

Comment: Oh ok thanks.
 I can see there are many resource but most of them claim it is a not stable solution as HHVM is still under development ( probably it will be worth to add the HHVM version you are using )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SSL not TLS

You're using Magento Aschroder_SMTPPro extension, Patch it !

[fixed stream_socket_enable_crypto() with HHVM + Magento + Aschroder_SMTPPro](https://github.com/hgati/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension/commit/8571187f7f10556454c57aae6917ddc4d990eb84)

Comment: Many thanks for your input. We have previously determined that `HHVM` did not meet our requirements and postponed the switch until it is improved. I was not aware that we were using `Aschroder_SMTPPro` - likely one of my colleague's additions. We will be soon reassessing whether `HHVM` is ready for our production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Problem not in `Zend_Mail_Protcol_Smtp`, as you wrote, `stream_socket_enable_crypto` not supported  by HHVM, so no matter how you replace `Zend_Mail_Protcol_Smtp`, if you want enabled crypto, you need to implement this function in HHVM.

Look at [this link](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/088eedfaa186e79f6f86b814f50efc947350bf88/ext/standard/streamsfuncs.c#L1493) for understanding how is `stream_socket_enable_crypto` implemented in PHP, then implement it to https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/blob/master/hphp/runtime/ext/stream/ext_stream.cpp .

Another way (bad): disable crypto for mail auth. Copy `lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php` to `app/code/local/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php` and comment lines 206-212:

```
if (!stream_socket_enable_crypto($this->_socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT)) {
    /**
     * @see Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception
     */
    #require_once 'Zend/Mail/Protocol/Exception.php';
    throw new Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception('Unable to connect via TLS');
}
```